Clone Button Not Visible In Salesforce Lightning
How to add or enable clone button for dashboards? The edit button is displaying. Clone button appears on Salesforce Classic.

I believe Clone should be available in Lightning but all I can see in Lightning experience is Save As.

The "Clone" button is typically used to create a new record that is a duplicate of an existing record. When you click "Clone", Salesforce creates a new record with the same field values as the original record, and you can then edit and save it as a new record.
The "Save As" button is often associated with reports and dashboards. It allows you to make a copy of the report or dashboard you're currently viewing and save it with a new name. You can then modify the copy without altering the original.

This is what I see in Lightning:
Also, Please check if they have the manage dynamic dashboard checked. Just manage dashboard will not give a clone button on the Dynamic dashboard, the only other difference will be modifying all data which I think you shouldn't be giving them

Manage dynamic dashboard is checked, also the link is not opening!

@rameesha updated the link

@rameesha, Refer to this: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387945&type=1

Clone is visible in Classic but not in Lightning, what could be the issue?

Have you see the Save As button?

Yes but why isnt clone appearing?

@rameesha, - The "Clone" button is typically used to create a new record that is a duplicate of an existing record. When you click "Clone", Salesforce creates a new record with the same field values as the original record, and you can then edit and save it as a new record.

The "Save As" button is often associated with reports and dashboards. It allows you to make a copy of the report or dashboard you're currently viewing and save it with a new name. You can then modify the copy without altering the original.


It's most likely a design decision by Salesforce. What is the benefit of having a clone button that is not achieved by using "Save As" to save a new/different version of the report?
